# MongoDB .Net driver 2.0 Builders Filter (field to array comparison)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I need to get all usernames from "followingList.username" and compare with 
posts' usernames, if there any match need to add that one to an array.

```
Person Model
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("554f20f5c90d3c7ed42303e1"),
    "username" : "fatihyildizhan",
    "followingList" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55505b6ca515860cbcf7901d"),
            "username" : "gumusluk",
            "avatar" : "avatar.png"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58505b6ca515860cbcf7901d"),
            "username" : "yalikavak",
            "avatar" : "avatar.png"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58305b6ca515860cbcf7901d"),
            "username" : "gumbet",
            "avatar" : "avatar.png"
        }
    ]
}

Post Model
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("554f2df2a388R4b425b89833"),
    "username" : "yalikavak",
    "category" : "Summer",
    "text" : "blue voyage with yacht"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("554f2df2a388P4b425b89833"),
    "username" : "yalikavak",
    "category" : "Winter",
    "text" : "is coming ..."
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("554f2df2a388K4b425b89833"),
    "username" : "gumbet",
    "category" : "Fall",
    "text" : "there are many trees"
}
```

I try to get result code block as below but couldn't figure it out.

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.AnyEq("username", usernameList);
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Can you help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic is flipped, what you need is an [`$in` query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) if I understand your use case correctly:

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.In("username", usernameList);
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

In your case, `username` is a simple field and you want to match against a list of candidates. `AnyEq` is used to check that, from an embedded list of complex objects, at least one matches a criterion. That still translates to a simple query in MongoDB, but requires to 'reach into' the object which needs a more complicated syntax.

Comment: Yeap, you got it right. "In" was the correct filter query that I was looking for. Thank you.